# Raspberry Pi and localhost Connection

Tags: pi-3, connection, locale

So I'm currently doing a project using Beacon and Raspberry Pi.
The raspberry pi collect the UUID and RSSI of the Beacon and send it using socket.io to the server ( localhost-my computer) to save it in database.

My question is how can the raspberry pi know the server, how can I do this connection between my RP AND Computer. 
P.S = I devlopped client and server side in NodeJs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a Raspberry Pi and a second computer.

You want to send data UUID and RSSI from the Raspberry Pi to the second computer.

There are three ways to do it that I can think of.

1. Using the IP adr of the second computer
2. Using the FQDN to the second computer.
3. Using mDNS to the second computer.